continues error on "Could not find 'Price' Did not find price on detail page" in django
im begginer in django , leanring through coursera , django for everyone course , while doing my assignment repeated error throwing contiusely while submitting
this is error,and 
i checked everthing but its still throwing error
but "price" is there in web
here my view.py in django-
from ads.models import Ad
from ads.owner import OwnerListView, OwnerDetailView, OwnerCreateView, OwnerUpdateView, OwnerDeleteView


class AdListView(OwnerListView):
    model = Ad


class AdDetailView(OwnerDetailView):
    model = Ad


class AdCreateView(OwnerCreateView):
    model = Ad
    fields = ['title', 'text', 'price']


class AdUpdateView(OwnerUpdateView):
    model = Ad
    fields = ['title', 'text', 'price']


class AdDeleteView(OwnerDeleteView):
    model = Ad

and here is my ad_detail.html ---
{% extends "base_menu.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ settings.APP_NAME }}{% endblock %}
{% load humanize %} <!-- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/humanize -->
{% block content %}
<span style="float: right;">
({{ ad.updated_at|naturaltime }})
{% if ad.owner == user %}
<a href="{% url 'ads:ad_update' ad.id %}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
<a href="{% url 'ads:ad_delete' ad.id %}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
{% endif %}
</span>
<h1>{{ ad.title }}</h1>
<p>
{{ ad.text }}
</p>
<p>
{{ ad.price }}
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="All Ads" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'ads:all' %}';return false;">
</p>
{% endblock %}

im using pythonanywhere for django and assignment
python manage.py check --ok
python manage.py makemigrations --ok
python manage.py migrate --ok
everything is fine but error aquries regularly pls someone help me
while submiting its show "Could not find 'Price' Did not find price on detail page" like this everytime

It looks like your test is looking for the text "Price" in the page and that is not there.

thqnk you i  made changes its worked now
